# How to know number of alternate setting supported by an USB Interface?

Tags: windows, usb, linux-device-driver

How can we know the number of Alternate setting supported by an Interface?
Is there any method/descriptor to get this information?

Thanks
Sathish.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following links:

Windows:[Thesycon USB Descriptor Dumper](http://www.thesycon.de/eng/usb_descriptordumper.shtml)

Linux:[lsusb](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/lsusb8.html)

Comment: Most of devices connected to my PC are showing bAlternateSetting value as 0, when I use lsusb. Is there any devices which has multiple Alternate settings for Interface?

Comment: Usually Audio Class Interface will have more than one alternate setting